# SQL Multiple update commands / bulk to temp table then join with update

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-update, sql-server-2012

i've a remote sql server that that have about 18k records, i need to do changes to it daily from my .net application.

when using multiple update queries to update couple thasands records at once it seems to take alot of time.

- is it better to bulk the updates to a temp table then join both
  tables and do updates?
- what is the best solution in such scenario?

what i am doing right now is looping through the records and bulding and update command and execute it for each record.

Comment: Theres almost always a faster way, but do you actually need it any faster if its a daily process?

Comment: @LukeMcGregor some times it happenes couple times per day based on data that i get online, when i test on my local sql server the speed is reasonable but on the remote server it really takes a lot of time, so would a bulk copy with update join make things faster?

Comment: probably, but it sounds like a lot of complexity when you probably dont need it, based on what you have just described it sounds like a command latency problem, this means you could get a substantial performance increase simply by parallelising sending commands to SQL

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a .net application and working with SQServer, I would make send the updated rows to the server as a table param to a stored procedure, and then do a simple UPDATE FROM or MERGE if you have INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE.